# Why do ArcGIS Area Calculations not match Official Statistics?

Tags: arcgis-10.1, coordinate-system, arcgis-desktop

I am trying to calculate area of polygons using a shapefile from the world bank where countries are defined.
When however I am trying to calcuate the area, the numbers that emerge are different from the official statistics on area.
Morever, whenever I use a different projection (e.g. equal area) and recalculate the area, I always get the same results.

Can someone tell me where the mistake could come from?

Thanks!

Comment: When you say "use" a different projection, do you mean that you've reprojected the data using the "project" tool or that you've just defined the projection as something else? Common mistake that I see around the office and on here. How different are your numbers from the official statistics to which you are comparing them? 10%? 50%?

Comment: I use ArcGIS 10.1. To change projection I go to Data Management tools->Projections and Transformations->Raster-Define Projection. Is this the right procedure? The differences lie in the range of 10-30%, thus not in a systematic way.

Comment: The "[Define Projection](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//001700000077000000)" tool does not reproject the data. Use the "Data Management tools->Projections and Transformations->Feature->[Project](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Project/00170000007m000000/)" tool instead.

Comment: Is your shapefile downloadable from somewhere (URL) for others to test?  What is the source (URL) of your official statistics?

Comment: My source is http://thematicmapping.org/downloads/world_borders.php. I project it at an equal area projection.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly you are using the wrong tool to project the data.

Secondly, the area and lengths calculated from geometry usually don't match the official statistics.  This is because of a variety of reasons including :

- The actual area on the ground is measured taking the terrain onto account.
- The way the official area is calculated, introduces many systematic error.
- The area is usually calculated in a local projection.
- The boundaries in your shapefile may not match the official boundary of the country.